# Word coloring and syntax analyzing

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, nlp

I want to colorize the words in a text according to their classification (category/declination etc). I have a fully working dictionary, but the problem is that there is a lot of ambiguity. `foedere`, for instance, can be forms of either the verb "fornicate" or the noun "treaty".

What the general strategies for solving these ambiguities or generating good guesses are?

Thanks!

Comment: A full fledged spell / grammar checker is the obvious solution, and as those still don't get everything right (but coming ever more close), I doubt there is a one-shot solution for you. You could check open source grammar checkers for their strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general strategy is to first run a [part-of-speech tagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) on the data to determine the word category (noun, verb, etc.). That, however, requires data (context statistics) and tools. [This research paper](http://gircse.marginalia.it/~passarotti/publications/Passarotti_SaLTMiL.pdf) may be a starting point.